# Producing Voronoi diagram in three dimensional

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, voronoi-diagrams

A Voronoi diagram is a kind of tesselation that divided the medium into polygons in 2D and polyhedrons in 3D.

Although there are many algorithms to construct a Voronoi diagram, some of them are faster than others. Based on my knowledge, Fortune's algorithm is fastest to construct the Voronoi diagram either in two dimensional or three dimensional.

Fortune's algorithm is based on the sweep-line strategy and balanced binary search tree.

Now, I want to implement Fortune's algorithm into three dimensional. I want to know which basically variation is made to fit the algorithm to three dimensional?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! You should check out http://math.lbl.gov/voro++/ by Chris Rycroft. It's the best implementation that I've come across, and there is documentation on the website. Whether you're looking for a tool to use or trying to implement it yourself for educational purposes, it's a good place to start.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3787491/14578, https://stackoverflow.com/q/63363508/781723, https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/35739/4274.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).